# Laravel excel dropdowns overriding to last one

Tags: excel, laravel, tensorflow-data-validation

foreach loop values override to last one. below is my code, please give me suggestions it's save my day.

```
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
            $worksheetNames = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
            $worksheetNames->setTitle('Field Names');
            $row = 1; // Start from row 1
            $column = 'A';
            
            foreach ($fieldData as $label) {
                    $checkFieldFunction = $label->Field_Function;
                
                    if ($checkFieldFunction == 4) {
                        $table = $label->From_Table;
                        $dropdownValues = DB::table($table)->get()->toArray();
                 $parse   = new DataValidation();
                 $drop_phase1 =  $column . ($row + 1);
                
                $dropdownOptions = array();
                
                foreach ($dropdownValues as $value) {
                     if ($label->From_Table == "Customers") {
                    $field_name = strtolower($label->{'Display Field'});
                            $fieldValue = property_exists($value, $field_name) ? $value->$field_name : null;
                            $dropdownOptions[] = $fieldValue;
                        } else {
                            $field_name = $label->{'Display Field'};
                            $fieldValue = property_exists($value, $field_name) ? $value->$field_name : null;
                            $dropdownOptions[] = $fieldValue;
                        }
                    }
                $validation=$worksheetNames->getCell($drop_phase1)->getDataValidation();
                $validation->setType(DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
                $validation->setErrorStyle(DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
                $validation->setAllowBlank(false);
                $validation->setShowInputMessage(true);
                $validation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
                $validation->setShowDropDown(true);
                $validation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
                $validation->setError('Value is not in list.');
                $validation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
                $validation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
                $validation->setFormula1(sprintf('"%s"', implode(',', $dropdownOptions)));
                $worksheetNames->getCell($drop_phase1)->setDataValidation(clone $validation);
                $worksheetNames->setCellValue($column . $row, $label->fld_label);
                $worksheetNames->setCellValue($column . ($row + 1), $label->Field_Name);
                $column++;
            }
        }  
         $fileName = $tableSelect . '.xlsx';
            $filePath = storage_path('app/' . $fileName);
        
            $writer->save($filePath);
        
            $headers = [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"',
            ];
        
            return response()->download($filePath, $fileName, $headers);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3wQG.png)    ``
[[here dropdown list override to last one of loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5L35.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GqN7.png)

I want dropdown need not to override, when am change to dynamic column for cell it gives excel error.